# False keyvalues are passed on keydown event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, key, keypress

I have a MDI parent form. When user presses Enter I want the Application to shut down.

I check the keydown event as follows:

```
 private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {

     if (e.KeyValue == (int)Keys.Enter) 
     {
                    Application.Exit();
     }
 }
```

Now it works fine, when I don't have any clickable controls on form (Button, TextBox etc). The `e.KeyValue` has the `(int)` value of Enter Key (13). But if I put some buttons or textboxes on to MDI Form, `e.KeyValue` brings the keyvalue of `Alt` Key i.e. 18. Why so ??

So now if I press `Alt+Enter`, the form closes; but not only on Enter Key

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to process the KeyPress a little sooner.  The following code will work for you:

```
    protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        int _ENTER = 13;
        int _KEYUP = 257;
        if (m.Msg == _ENTER && (int)m.WParam == _KEYUP)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly. I just edited your answer by swapping the _KEYUP and _ENTER. Because m.MSG will give _KEYUP and not _ENTER.

Comment: I would still like to know, why so ?
I will accept it as an answer in few mins. I am just waiting if someone reverts to answer my 'Why so' part !

Comment: The key is processed by the control that currently has focus. 
So if you press "Enter" - focused control will process the key first. If you use additional key "Alt" - it doesn't force focused control to process the key.
You also may try "Ctrl" + "Enter" - it also should be processed by the form. There is a special Form.KeyPreview property, but it looks that it works improperly in most cases. So you should override ProcessKeyPreview or ProcessDialogKey methods in the form for handling keys before any control.

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.KeyCode and e.Modifiers;`

Comment: i tried doing this: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt)`
           `{`
                `Application.Exit();`
           `}` But still not working