# Detect in Control.GotFocus whether user navigates forward or backward?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

Having the following WinForms dialog form, I am handling the [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ongotfocus.aspx) event of `MyControl`:

[image]

`MyControl` derives from the DevExpress [`XtraUserControl`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsXtraUserControltopic) which in turn derives from the Microsoft WinForms standard [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

What I want to achieve is that when `MyControl` gets the focus when the user navigates with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and `MyControl` gets the focus, that the focus is forwarded to the child controls.

I do this successfully with the following code:

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);

    // Forward.
    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        if (control.TabStop)
        {
            control.Select();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I.e. if `Button 1` is focused and the user presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, the focus is set to `Button 2`.

What I'm *not* able to solve is if the user navigates backward. I.e. if `Button 4` is focused and the user presses the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys, the focus should be set to `Button 3`.

**My two questions are:**

- Is there a way to detect the navigation order of the user inside the `GotFocus` event?
- Am I doing it the right way at all? Maybe there is a built-in function/flag I can set to `MyControl` to automatically forward the focus to its child controls?

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804539/how-to-find-previous-active-control-c-sharp

Comment: As you can see with the useless `EventArgs` parameter of the `GotFocus` event, you can't say what set the focus to your control (tab, shit+tab, left click, right click....). There isn't any simple way of doing what you asked AFAIK.

Comment: The bigger question is how the UserControl got the focus.  It doesn't want the focus, it passes the focus immediately to a client control when it does.

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant - I'll investigate whether I did something wrong when creating the control.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, the truth is, I'm deriving from a DevExpress `XtraUserControl` control which in turn derives from `UserControl`. Maybe this is the cause of getting the focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many possibilities:

- use the OnLostFocus event to store the current control and calculate whether TAB or SHIFT TAB was pressed
- override ProcessKeyPreview to calc the action to be performed in OnGotFocus ([SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5761981/21336))
- override ProcessCmdKey as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1873133/21336)